# NullPointerException in JavaFX initialize method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx

I have controller and there I trying get INBOX folder from e-mail server. With downloading everything is ok. I can put this data(email subject,from,date) into TableView but... only when I am waiting for thread responsible for set this data in TableView. 
Code:

```
// The table and columns
@FXML
TableView<MainModel.Item> itemTbl;
@FXML
TableColumn itemNameCol;
@FXML
TableColumn itemQtyCol;
@FXML
TableColumn itemTitleCol;
// The table's data
static ObservableList<MainModel.Item> data;

public void dataSet(){
    // Set up the table data
    itemNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<MainModel.Item,String>("name")
    );
    itemQtyCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<MainModel.Item,String>("qty")
    );
    itemTitleCol.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<MainModel.Item,String>("title")
    );

    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    itemTbl.setItems(data);
}

public void setEnemyEvent() {
    itemTbl.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                if(itemTbl.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()!=null){
                    System.out.println(itemTbl.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().name);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
    setEnemyEvent();
    dataSet();
    Thread t = new Thread(new MessageLoop());
    //HERE:
    t.start();
    //of course normally here is try and catch
    t.join();
}

//staric nested class "for loop"
private static class MessageLoop implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            EmailConnetion con = new EmailConnetion();
            MainModel MainModel = new MainModel();
            for(int i=0;i<con.message.length;i++){
                try{
                    MainModel.Item item = MainModel.new Item();
                    item.name.setValue(i+""+con.message[i].getFrom()[0].toString());
                    item.qty.setValue(con.message[i].getSentDate().toString());
                    item.title.setValue(con.message[i].getSubject().toString());
                    //Here is a problem.
                    data.add(item);//This indicate my IDE  
                    //*****************
                } catch(AddressException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error : " + "AddressException:"+i);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

When i remove t.join() it will throw this NullPointerException.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.callObservers(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:74)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$3.onChanged(TableView.java:1725)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:134)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.callObservers(ObservableListWrapper.java:97)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.clear(ObservableListWrapper.java:184)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.quietClearSelection(TableView.java:2154)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.updateSelection(TableView.java:1902)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.access$2600(TableView.java:1681)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$8.onChanged(TableView.java:1802)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:71)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.callObservers(ObservableListWrapper.java:97)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.add(ObservableListWrapper.java:154)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.add(ObservableListWrapper.java:144)
    at javasplitpane.SimpleController$MessageLoop.run(SimpleController.java:95)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This appear in different position, in fourteen email, thirty email. You have some ideas ?

p.s I can't wait for this downloading because it takes 20 sec. with 50 emails - I have to do it during initialize.

Comment: Don't name your variables with the same case as their Class.

Comment: The `data` it isn't initialized, initialize it.

Comment: I have initialized it (data is in other file) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Your Error**

Don't modify anything which is connected to the active scene graph from any other thread than the JavaFX Application Thread.

**Background Information**

See the [JavaFX Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) and also [Usage of JavaFX Platform.runLater and access to UI from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160410/usage-of-javafx-platform-runlater-and-access-to-ui-from-a-different-thread/15160824#15160824) for an explanation of this rule.

As your data list is an [ObservableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) backing a [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) displayed in the active scene graph, as you modify the ObservableList, it fires change events to the TableView modifying it from your user thread rather than the JavaFX Application Thread - this causes race conditions and inconsistent program failures.

**How to Fix it**

To fix your issue, wrap the call to update the data item inside [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    data.add(item);
  }
});
```

The contents of the `run` method submitted to `Platform.runLater` are executed on the JavaFX Application Thread.