# JavaFX GUI freezes within Platform.runLater

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have the following piece of code:

```
@FXML public void initialize() {
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                for(int i=0 ; i<10 ;i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    exampleButton.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                }
            }catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    });
}
```

Which should obviously change the text of the button every second.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755031/how-javafx-application-thread-works) question, I put the `sleep` and the `setText` into a `Platform.runLater`-block, since GUI-modifications should not be done from the main thread. But my GUI is still freezing.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The loop is running on the "main event thread", preventing it from processing any new threads.  This is kind of concurrency 101 - you should start by taking a look at [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Comment: @MadProgrammer is totally right, use a `Task` or maybe a `Service` from `javafx.concurrent` package

Comment: You could simply use a `Timeline` to do this. Of course, you need to make sure your controller class holds a strong reference of that `Timeline`. Also note that you do not need `@FXML` annotation if your `initialize()` method is `public`.