# JavaFX - Using Task<> to run a jobs in the background lags the program

Tags: java, javafx, task

I'm trying to write an implementation of [MapPanel by Stepan Rutz](https://github.com/srutz/mappanel) in JavaFX.

Stepan's map allows the user to move around the map while the map tiles haven't been loaded and I'm trying to get that same effect.To do it I'm using `Task<>` to run the painting of the tiles in the background whenever is required (pretty often).

The thing is that whenever a new tile that hasn't been painted before needs to be added to the map the program creates a new worker to do the task of creating the tile (a petition to my server where they are created).

I think that I need to restrain somehow the number of tasks that are being created but I don't know how to accomplish it while having the sensation of smoothness when moving the map.

Here is the code that creates the tiles:

1.First a for loop for every tile that is needed:

```
    public void paintMap(Point mapPosition, Point scalePosition) {
        double width = this.getWidth();
        double height = this.getHeight();

        int x0 = (int) Math.floor((this.mapPosition.getX()) / TILE_SIZE);
        int y0 = (int) Math.floor((this.mapPosition.getY()) / TILE_SIZE);
        int x1 = (int) Math.ceil((mapPosition.getX() + width) / TILE_SIZE);
        int y1 = (int) Math.ceil((mapPosition.getY() + height) / TILE_SIZE);
        
        int dy = y0 * TILE_SIZE - (int) this.mapPosition.getY();
        for(int y = y0; y < y1; ++y) {
            int dx = x0 * TILE_SIZE - (int) this.mapPosition.getX();
            for(int x = x0; x < x1; ++x) {

                paintTile(dx, dy, x, y);
                dx += TILE_SIZE;
            }
            dy += TILE_SIZE;
        }
    }
```

2. The function that paints the tile:

```
    private void paintTile(int dx, int dy, int x, int y) {
        int xTileCount = 1 << zoom;
        int yTileCount = 1 << zoom;
        boolean tileInBounds = x >= 0 && x < xTileCount && y >= 0 && y < yTileCount;
        if(tileInBounds) {
            TileCache cache = getCache();
            Image image = cache.get(x, y, zoom);
            if(image == null) {
                String tileURL = getTileString(x,y, zoom);
                System.out.println(tileURL);
                invokeTileTaskController(this, tileURL, cache, x, y, dx, dy);

            }
            if(image != null) {
                ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
                iv.setX(dx);
                iv.setY(dy);
                this.getChildren().add(iv); 
                iv = null;

            }
        }
    }
```

3. The function that creates the task:

```
private void invokeTileTaskController(MapPanel mp, String tileURL, TileCache cache, int x, int y, int dx, int dy) {
        TileTaskController ttc = new TileTaskController(tileURL);
        Thread ttcThread = new Thread(ttc);
        ttcThread.start();
        ttc.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, 
                new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                Image tileImage = ttc.getValue();
                if(tileImage!=null) {
                    cache.put(x, y, zoom, tileImage);
                    ImageView iv = new ImageView(tileImage);
                    iv.setX(dx);
                    iv.setY(dy);
                    mp.getChildren().add(iv);
                }
            }
        });     
    }
```

4. And the Task class:

```
public class TileTaskController extends Task<Image>
{
    private Image tileImage;
    private final String tileURL;
    public TileTaskController(String tileURL) 
    {
        this.tileImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("image-error-icon-7.jpg"));
        this.tileURL = tileURL;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Image call() throws Exception 
    {
        Image tileImage = new Image(this.tileURL);
        updateValue(tileImage);
        return new Image(this.tileURL);
    }

}
```

Comment: All code that updates the [JavaFX] GUI **must** run on the [JavaFX application thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755031/how-javafx-application-thread-works). It looks to me like you are updating the GUI from the worker thread. Did I misunderstand your code?

Comment: You don’t need a Task or Thread just to load an image in the background.  Just use `new Image(tileURL, true)`.  The second argument [specifies background loading](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,boolean)).

Comment: The solution provided by @VGR solves the problem. Thank you! 

I'll take a look to the other comments later to see if they improve anything else.

Comment: Using the built-in image background loading is the correct approach here, but note that in your original `Task` implementation you load the image twice, for no reason. There is no need to call `updateValue()`; the value will be updated to the value returned from the `call()` method anyway, so all you need is `protected Image call() { return new Image(this.tileURL); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by @vgr no `Task<>` is needed to avoid lagging and load multiple images simultaneously. Just adding the parameter `true` to the `Image` with the url does the trick:

```
Image i = new Image(URL, true);
```

This way JavaFX loads the image in the background and loads it whenever its ready, solving the multitasking problem I had.